# tableview with text fields in each row having resignkeypad issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

i am adding the textfield on each row inside the cellforrow method of tableview,but when i type anything on any textfield ind try to resign textfield on view touch, but it only works for last row's textfield only. what is the solution for that issue, 
please help.

Thanks 
Dhananjay

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. Please try to explain it more clearly. Posting the code in question would be a good idea as well.

Comment: - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {
 NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
 [partreference_tbl_textfield resignFirstResponder];
   }

Comment: I'm guessing (I say guessing because there is no code) but your probably assigning in a loop and only the last assignment is sticking?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly this will probably work:

add the  protocol to your viewController in question and add

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];

// custom code
}
```

afterwards make sure that each textField has your viewController as delegate.